# Help! What set is this?

Tags: set-identification, instructions

[image]I have a lego bag only. I am trying to figure out what set the bag goes to. It's bag number 3 and has pieces that look like they go to a green vehicle of some sort. Possibly a truck?

Answer (score 8):

Spider-Man: Spider-Cycle Chase (Set 76004)

[image]

I found this by going to bricklink.com, searching for a recognizable piece, then seeing which sets that piece could be found in.

Comment: Thank you very much! Seems to be a good fit.